# Google protocol buffers compare

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to compare two **Messages** or (two sub parameters) of [Google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).
I don't find an API to achieve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want to compare: message structure, message's field values or the both at once?

Answer (score 50):

You can use the class [google::protobuf::util::MessageDifferencer](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.h) for this. I think it's only available since [v3.0.2](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.2):

> Introduced new utility functions/classes in the google/protobuf/util
> directory:
>
> - MessageDifferencer: compare two proto messages and report their differences.

```
#include <google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.h>

MessageDifferencer::Equals(msg1, msg2);
```

Comment: To add: MessageDifferencer is available for C++ only

Comment: depending on whether fields in your Message types can have default values, you might want to consider `MessageDifferencer::Equivalent` instead of `Equals`

Comment: Indeed, I had a unit test failing on comparing binary and string variants of a complex message structure, but the MessageDifferencer fixes it!

Comment: Note that unfortunately this doesn't work if you are using the lite version of the library, as `MessageDifferencer::Equals` requires the arguments to be `Message` and not `MessageLite` (from which `Message` derives). `Equals` requires `GetDescriptor()` which is a feature only implemented in `Message`.
So in that case one has to go for one of the serialization methods mentioned in the other answers, well aware of the limitations.

Answer (score 14):

You can rely on the fact that all of your protobuf messages inherit from the [`google::protobuf::MesageLite`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite) type, which in turn has everything you need to compare any two protobuf messages, regardless of if they are even of the same derived type:

```
bool operator==(const google::protobuf::MessageLite& msg_a,
                const google::protobuf::MessageLite& msg_b) {
  return (msg_a.GetTypeName() == msg_b.GetTypeName()) &&
      (msg_a.SerializeAsString() == msg_b.SerializeAsString());
}
```

---

**EDIT**

As was pointed out in the comments below, and especially for `map` fields, this answer is incorrect. `map` elements have non-deterministic ordering. Use `MessageDifferencer` if `map` fields might be present in your messages.

Comment: Wow. This should be a perfect answer to this user's question! Bravo!

Comment: This method is faster than `MessageDifferencer::Equals(msg1, msg2);`

Comment: From their documentation:
> The following checks may fail for a protocol buffer message instance foo: foo.SerializeAsString() == foo.SerializeAsString()
This is due to non-determinism of field orders when encoding a message:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#order

Comment: In practice, I've found the above comment to be especially true for `map` fields. If your protobuf messages might have `map` fields, `SerializeAsString()` is going to fail non-deterministically.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `message.DebugString` you could also do

```
std::string strMsg;
message.SerializeToString(&strMsg);
```

with both messages and then compare the two (binary) strings. I didn't test the performance but I assume that it is faster than comparing the human readable message strings returned by .DebugString(). +You can do that with the protobuf-lite library (while for message.DebugString you need the full version).

Comment: The serialization isn't guaranteed to be consistent across binaries and over time. For example, extensions that are unknown to a binary will be serialized last (as unknown fields), after known extensions. So the serialization will depend on what descriptors are available at the time of serialization. Comparing the serialized messages is therefore a bad was to check for equality. MessageDifferencer is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a protocol buffer is just a serialization format for some object type. Why not use the protocol buffer to reconstruct the original objects, and then allow those objects to compare themselves, using whatever comparison logic you've built into the class?

Comment: That is my understanding.  According to this: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#not-good-fit, "When protocol buffers are serialized, the same data can have many different binary serializations. You cannot compare two messages for equality without fully parsing them."

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the ideal solution, but I think it could be done by:

```
messageA.DebugString() == messageB.DebugString();
```

Other than that, I think the only solution would be to create your own `Message` child class and implement a `bool operator==(const Message&)`.

Comment: @idimba Tks.  But then I guess you should edit your question and mention the speed thing ;-).  But then, I guess, the only real option would be to implement the comparison operator yourself.

Comment: @Yousf It is not, as Protobuf docs say, that inheriting from Message is not the way to go. I agree with that, as you will have to change file generated by protoc, so changing original proto will be difficult, as you will have to change it **every** compilation.

Answer (score -6):

You can compare the descriptor's pointer (super fast):

```
if (mMessages[i]->body()->GetDescriptor() == T::descriptor())
```

mMessages it's a pool of network messages with header and crypto which creates a packet with the protobuf body(google::protobuf::Message*).

so, to get the right kind of message i compare the descriptors constant pointer which is the same for every single type of message (not %100 sure but i haven't got any problem so far).

That would be the fastest way to compare a protobuf Message wthout having to use string comparasion, which by the way you gan get the type name from the descriptor. :-)

Comment: Love how my answer got voted down, but it is the right way to comparare messages.

Comment: That would be correct if you wanted to compare the types, but this question would seem to be about comparing the contents, which this most certainly does not do. This is why you got the downvote, I'd warrant.