# Compare two Repeated Fields with the C++ API

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have two instances of the following protobuf structure:

```
message customStruct
{
    optional int32  a = 1;
    optional int32  b = 2;
}

message info
{
    repeated customStruct  cs = 1;
    optional int32         x = 2;
    optional double        y = 3;
}

message root
{
    optional info inf =  1;
}
```

[I know I can compare Messages with the C++ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228107/google-protocol-buffers-compare) but I would like to directly compare two Repeated Fields (`customStruct` here), for simplicity and perhaps performance optimization.

Ideally, I would need a C++ equivalent of the C# method [Equals(RepeatedField< T > other)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_collections_1_1_repeated_field_3_01_t_01_4_1a2607441aec8ecb9341beafaeb03e5d14).

Is that feasible in C++? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RepeatedField<T>`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field) has STL-like iterators, so you can use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) to compare them:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <...>

const google::protobuf::ReapeatedField<int32> & myField1 = ...;
const google::protobuf::ReapeatedField<int32> & myField2 = ...;
bool fieldsEqual = std::equal(myField1.begin(), myField1.end(), myField2.begin());
```

Comment: @GrégoireBorel Well, yes, there is an overload of `std::equals` that accepts a binary predicate (like a lambda), or you could have `operator==` defined in your struct.

Comment: What struct? We're talking generated c++ classes here. You don't want to add onto those. Could you give a minimal working example please?

Comment: @hasdrubal Yes, you're right, adding `operator==` to the autogenerated types wouldn't work. You can however define the operator as a free function (`bool operator==(const MyMessage& a, const MyMessage& b) { /* ... */ }`) or pass it as a binary predicate (`std::equal(myField1.begin(), myField1.end(), myField2.begin(), [] (const MyMessage& a, const MyMessage& b) { /* ... */ });`).

Answer (score -1):

To augment @jdehesa's answer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <...>

const google::protobuf::ReapeatedField<int32> & myField1 = ...;
const google::protobuf::ReapeatedField<int32> & myField2 = ...;
bool fieldsEqual = std::equal(myField1.begin(), myField1.end(), myField2.begin(), 
google::protobuf::utils::MessageDifferencer::Equals);
```

Comment: The namespace should be 

```google::protobuf::util```

instead of ```google::protobuf::utils```

Comment: ```
static bool Equals(const Message& message1, const Message& message2);
```

The definition of Equals is like this.
Hence you can't use it for the above comparison.