# Using protobuf objects as key in the std::map

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I'm new to the concept of protocol buffers and have a task at hand that can be resolved if I use the protobuf object as keys in the `std::map`.

I know to be able to use protobuf object as key, I need to provide a custom comparator to the `std::map` to maintain the ordering of the keys.

I have two questions at this point in time:

1. Is there any utility function/class in the google/protobuf/util that overloads less than operator for comparing two protobuf messages? i.e., something similar to this.

```
bool operator<(google::protobuf::Message m1, google::protobuf::Message m2){
    // compare the protobuf messages
    // and finally return the value
    return value;
}
```

2. Any potential side effects that I might be aware of, which might arise as a result of using a protobuf object as key?

Comment: Do you really need an `std::map`? Can you work with `std::unordered_map` instead?

Comment: Yes, but in that case I'd need an equality and a hashing function for the protobuf messages. There's an Equals function in the protobuf utils module, but no hashing function.

Comment: @MukulGupta is there any function in utils module to calculate hash of a protobuf message?

Comment: Not in C++ as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest it's better to use `std::unordered_map` rather than `std::map` if you don't care about the order. This is not only optimal but also less error prone. In case of the comparator implementation, you will have to make sure if `Message m1` is greater than `Message m2` and `Message m2` is greater than `Message m3`, then `Message m1` is greater than `Message m3`. (mentioning since this wasn't clear to me from your definition).

You can use the [MessageDifferencer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer#MessageDifferencer.Equals.details) as a replacement to `std:equal_to`. See also answers at [Google protocol buffers compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228107/google-protocol-buffers-compare)

However, as you correctly point out that there is no equivalent to `std::hash`, you will need to provide a custom hash function. Please refer to [PR-2066](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2066) and [PR-2304](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/2304) which discuss about this missing functionality.

From the pull request, quoting [xfxyjwf](https://github.com/xfxyjwf):

> It's not a very good idea to use proto message as keys because they are not true value types. With the presence of unknown fields, two equal messages in one binary might be treated as different by another, and therefore two different binaries might get two different unordered_map<> even given the exactly same input data (if the hash function is implemented using MessageDifferencer). It's probably better to write your own hash function that has your desired behavior rather than replying on a generic one.

If you don't have unknown fields, a generic hash function should work fine.