# How to mock a Function arguments with no operator== using Gmock

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, googletest, googlemock

I am using Gmock for unit tests.
I have function who receive protobuf message as an argument.
The problem is that when I'm testing the function with expected value it gives me an error of missing operator==.
I found similar problem here [google-protocol-buffers-compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228107/google-protocol-buffers-compare)

```
class ClientReaderWriterMock : public ClientReaderWriterIf {
 public:
  virtual ~ClientReaderWriterMock() = default;
  MOCK_METHOD1(Write, bool(const Msg&));
  MOCK_METHOD1(Read, bool(Msg*));
};

TEST_F(controller_Test, receive_message) {
Msg msg;
.
.
.
EXPECT_CALL(*clientReaderWriterMockObj, Write(msg));
.
.
.
}
```

I receive the following error:

> ###>/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h: In instantiation of ‘bool testing::internal::AnyEq::operator()(const
> A&, const B&) const [with A = Msg; B = Msg]’:
> /###>/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:549:18:
> required from ‘bool testing::internal::ComparisonBase<D, Rhs,
> Op>::Impl<Lhs,  >::MatchAndExplain(Lhs,
> testing::MatchResultListener*) const [with Lhs = const Msg&;
>  = Msg; D = testing::internal::EqMatcher;
> Rhs = Msg; Op = testing::internal::AnyEq]’
> /###>/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:547:10:
> required from here
> /###>/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h:211:60:
> error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const Msg’ and
> ‘const Msg’)   211 |   bool operator()(const A& a, const B& b) const {
> return a == b; } In file included from
> /###>/tests/unit/test.cpp:2:
> /###>/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:1535:13:
> note: candidate: ‘bool
> testing::internal::operator==(testing::internal::faketype,
> testing::internal::faketype)’  1535 | inline bool operator==(faketype,
> faketype) { return true; }
> /###>/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:1535:24:
> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Msg’ to
> ‘testing::internal::faketype’  1535 | inline bool operator==(faketype,
> faketype) { return true; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an expect call is set on a function with some arguments, the `Eq` matcher is used (implicitly), so the line:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*clientReaderWriterMockObj, Write(msg));
```

is actually:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*clientReaderWriterMockObj, Write(Eg(msg)));
```

`Eq` matcher will try to invoke `operator==` (which is missing as you noticed). In such case, you can define your own matcher:

```
MATCHER_P(CustomMatcher, expected, "Msg doesn't match!") {
    // your comparision code here
    return arg.Field() == expected.Field();
}
[...]
EXPECT_CALL(*clientReaderWriterMockObj, Write(CustomMatcher(msg)));
```